# Iterating through a jQuery Array and using $.inArray inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Here is my `Array`, this comes out of a `jQuery` `.post` success `function`:

```
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $(".chk_permission_").each(function() {
            if ($.inArray($(this).val(), data)) {
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
            } else {
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
```

when I `alert` data, I get the correct two values.  I have ten checkboxes, all with class `chk_permission_`.  Two of the values of these checkboxes contain the data in the array.  however when I run the above code:  For all users that return ANYThing back in the `data` array, the first box is unchecked, the rest is checked. For everyone else, that returns null (which means no boxes should be checked), all ten boxes are checked.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray) returns the index of the item in the array if it is found else returns -1

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
$(".chk_permission_").each(function () {
    $(this).prop("checked", $.inArray($(this).val(), data) > -1);
});
```

so if the item is found in position `0`, it returns `0` which is a falsy value so instead of the `if` block `else` block will get executed

Comment: That was it exactly.  Thank you.  I am used to handling this in php with `in_array` and tried to use it like that.  Thanks!

Comment: If this is the right answer, be sure to mark it so.